# Доступ к папке по сети

Tags: linux, linux-mint

Моя система: Linux Mint 17.2

В моём ноутбуке 2 винта

1. SSD, разметка MBR, один активный primary (ext4), на нём установлен Linux, на нём лежит домашняя папка /home.
2. HDD, разметка GPT, один primary раздел (ext4) "DATA", на нём лежат мои данные.

Далее я хочу отдать в доступ для чтения для всех весь раздел DATA

[image: Раздел DATA]

Но, когда я пытаюсь зайти по сети на этот ресурс, то мне отказано в доступе.
Если я таким образом расшарю любой другой ресурс на домашней папке /home, то все нормально.

Почему так?
Как сделать доступ к разделу?
Расшаривать отдельные папки нет возможности, их очень много.

[image: Права and]

```
and@and-MS-1738 ~ $ mount
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/1000/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,user=and)
/dev/sdb1 on /media/and/DATA type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

Comment: Убрал форматирование заголовков. Вопрос и так прекрасно читается. )

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу вывод программы `mount` после того, как вы просмотрите содержимое раздела `data`. это позволит дать вам дальнейшие рекомендации.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так `udisks` примонтировал раздел (после вашего к нему обращения) для использования **вами**:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/and/DATA type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2)
```

чтобы монтирование происходило автоматически и для использования всеми, во-первых, надо создать каталог, в который будет происходить монтирование, во-вторых, внести соответствующую запись в `/etc/fstab`.

каталог может иметь произвольное имя. удобно располагать подобные каталоги в каталоге `/media`:

```
$ sudo mkdir /media/data
```

запись в `/etc/fstab` должна выглядеть примерно так:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

хотя, для надёжности, можно заменить «позиционную» привязку раздела (`/dev/sdb1`) на «именную» (я так понимаю, что разделу присвоен *label* `DATA`):

```
LABEL="DATA" /media/data ext4 defaults 0 0
```

убедитесь, что всё происходит правильно после перезагрузки и в каталог `/media/data` монтируется нужный вам раздел.

а после этого можете уже «расшаривать» этот каталог, как вы и хотели, по [протоколу smb](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block).

Comment: Сейчас уже за домашним компом, и там у меня стоит Ubuntu 15.04  схема винтов такая же и задача собственно та же, создал папку /media/data  вставил в fstab UUID=58241A2D241A0F1E /media/data ext4 defaults 0 0 ,  после чего система даже не загрузилась (UUID проверял, правильный), зависла на черном экране, пришлось откатить fstab

Comment: @AND, это уже совсем другой вопрос. задать его можно, нажав кнопку [задать вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) в правом верхнему углу страницы.

Comment: Всё, разобрался, заработало, забыл, что у меня дома раздел DATA ntfs, а не ext4. Огромное спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том что на раздел DATA у вас установлены права на пользователя root:wheel ибо он под ними монтируется, а на /home - пользователя под которым заходите. Как вариант - расшаривать конкретную папку в DATA, на которую есть соответствующие права

**UPD:**

Попрбуйте сменить права при автомонтировании раздела. Что-нибудь вроде:

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/DATA  ext4 rw,noauto,users,uid=1000,gid=1000,permissions 0 2
```

Comment: В том то и дело, что права root я менял на свои.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять права непосредственно при монтировании раздела

Comment: На втором скрине у меня видно что владелец "and", этого разве не достаточно?

Comment: Я новичёк в линуксе, в каком файле происходит автомонтирование?